# Xamarin Forms: How to give exact circle background for icons?

Tags: image, xamarin.forms, background

I have some icons on my xamarin forms project. I need a circle background for my icon. See the screenshot below:

[image]

I tried `Xam.Plugins.Forms.ImageCircle` plugin and tried `Framelayout`. `Imagecircle` plugin only cropping the icon and `Framelayout` gives a rounded corner layout. Nothing gives me a perfect circle background. I go through the `FFImageloading` documentation, but which is also the same as `Imagecircle` plugin.

**Image code**

```
<Image 
   Source="ic_group_fill_xx.png"
   WidthRequest="25"
   HeightRequest="25"/>
```

Is there any way to achieve this feature?

Comment: I usually prefer to make an icon that by default has a circle doesn't make sense to add extra code for something that can be done for free

Comment: The ability to implement this using code is limited and time consuming, and it is recommended to provide an adapted image size to quickly resolve this issue.

Comment: @G.hakim Can you please post the comment as your answer, then I can close this thread.

Comment: @SreejithSree Done you may take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually prefer to make an icon that by default has a circle in it, doesn't make sense to add extra code for something that can be done for free.

There is great document by Android on working with Images for Android applications which can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio), you can also use [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) for creating awesome images.

Answer (score 2):

I normally use an ImageButton for this (and because of the clicked property you don't need to use Gesture Recognizers for detecting taps)

The code below gives me a perfect circle on Android & iOS

```
<ImageButton Source="icon_name"
                     BackgroundColor="Blue"
                     HeightRequest="60"
                     WidthRequest="60"
                     CornerRadius="30"
                     Padding="15"
                     Clicked="Btn_Clicked" />
```

*The image below is from my app, the image button is inside AbsoluteLayout and the icon is 64x64*
[image: Image Button Used in-app it has the same properties as the code above)]

Comment: I tried this, but getting a rounded corner square like frame layout, screenshot added to the question.

Comment: Looks like the Width of your ImageButton is being overwritten, can you make sure it doesn't have a property like HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" or something else of this sort

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`ImageCircle.Forms.Plugn`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Forms.ImageCircle) plugin which I am already using it,
Import namespace like below,

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin"
```

And use the image control like below sample,

```
<controls:CircleImage 
          Source="{Binding ProfileImage}" 
          HorizontalOptions="Start" 
          VerticalOptions="Center" 
          WidthRequest="40" 
          Aspect="AspectFill" 
          BorderColor="#B8BCC9" 
          BorderThickness="1" 
          HeightRequest="40" />
```

Comment: On the question itself, I mention about this solution. The `CircleImage` plugin only crops the image As a result, the circle always touches the icon. We can't apply `padding` for `circleimages`. I added a screenshot to the question now.